# Thrift How to realize the paging

Tags: thrift

I use thrift .I want do paging logic.How to do?

for example in java I can do it

```
Class Page{
  public int total; 
  public int pageSize; 
  public int pageNum; 
  public int totalPageNum; 
  public List<T> elements; 
}
Page findXx（）{
   return page;
}
```

how to do it with thrift . thrift  does not support generic

Comment: struct PageRange {
        1: i32 startPageNum
        2: i32 pageSize
        3: i32 totalPageNum
        4: i32 totalNum
}
  map<PageRange,list<T>> query（）
can do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use map to do it。 but it is ugly。

```
   struct PageRange {
        1: i32 startPageNum
        2: i32 pageSize
        3: i32 totalPageNum
        4: i32 totalNum
}
  map<PageRange,list<T>> query（）；
```